# Thin gaps in shadows of FBX models imported into Unity

Tags: unity, blender, shadows, fbx, 3d-modeling

I recently have started making my game in Unity and making models to go alongside it. However, I export my models as an FBX and am able to successfully get them into the game, but unfortunately it looks like this.

[image]

There are thin lines that show straight through the mesh despite there being no holes visible in my mesh. Is this a unity shading error, or something completely different?

Comment: This isn't a normal Unity artifact. You may want to double-check that your meshes are water-tight.

Comment: Another thing to check: where is the directional light relative to these meshes, and are they in front of its near plane distance?